# Creating dummy variables for movies

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I would like to create a dummy variables for action movies in my data set.

My code is,

```
imdb$action_movies <- ifelse(imdb$imdb.com_genres == "Action", 1,0)
```

Unfortunately when I run this code I only get movies with exclusively the `Action` tag and not movies with multiple tags such as Action Adventure.

How can I make it so that my dummy variable will include movies that have the action tag and multiple other genres?

Comment: Provide a sample dataset it will make things clear.

Comment: More specifically, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example So the easiest way would be to use `dput(your data)` and copy the result here, or, if the data is too large, use `dput(head(your data))`.

Comment: simplest version is `grepl("Action", imdb$imdb.com_genres)`. NB that you don't need the `ifelse` in your code. Just the `==` or `grepl` will create a logical variable, which will be interpreted as 1/0 if used in a numeric context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively simple problem that regex that can solve.

Basically we want to inspect every string to see if it contains "Action". If it does we give it a 1, if it does not a 0.

We can use `str_detect()` from `{stringr}` to do this.

From there we throw our matches into an `ifelse()` statement as you had done above.

An example of what the final column will look like this is shown below

```
movies <- c("Action", "Comedy, Action, Adventure", "Action, Adventure")
imdb$action_movies <- ifelse(str_detect(movies, "Action") == T, 1, 0)
```

Which returns

```
[1] 1 1 1
```